# extract a smaller number from a larger number

Tags: java

I am in a situation where I want to take a `long UPC //12 digits` and extract digits 1-6 and store them as `private final MANUFACTURER_ID` and also digits 7-11 to store as `private final ITEM_NUMBER`. I have a block of code that does this task in a rather ugly and roundabout manner, and I'm sure there's a more concise and correct way to do so.

Here is the relevant code in the InventoryItem class, which has the UPC variable. Is there a different, more concise way to do this, regarding the section which extracts numbers from UPC?

```
public InventoryItem(
        long UPC, 
        Category category, 
        Unit_Of_Measure unitOfMeasure, 
        String binLocation, 
        String aisle, 
        String name, 
        String description, 
        short itemsPerUOM,
        int unitsInStock,
        int unitsLastReceived){

    this.UPC = UPC;
    this.category = category;
    this.unitOfMeasure = unitOfMeasure;
    this.binLocation = binLocation;
    this.aisle = aisle;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.itemsPerUOM = itemsPerUOM;
    this.unitsInStock = unitsInStock;
    this.unitsLastReceived = unitsLastReceived;


    /* The code block below parses and extracts digits 1-6 of a UPC which is
     * the unique manufacturer ID. This block also repeats the same process for
     * digits 7-11 which are the manufacturer-specific Item Number. After these
     * steps, the temp Strings are converted to their long integer values and
     * used to initialize MANUFACTURER_ID and ITEM_NUMBER. The 12th digit of a 
     * UPC is used for checksum and thus is ignored for the scope of this program */


    String str = Long.toString(UPC);
    String tempManufacturerID = "";
    String tempItemNumber = "";
    char[] chArr = str.toCharArray();

    //extract the manufacturer ID
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        tempManufacturerID += String.valueOf(chArr[i]);
    }

    //extract the manufacturer's item number
    for(int i = 6; i < 11; i++){
        tempItemNumber += String.valueOf(chArr[i]);
    }

    // unbox and assign the extracted data to their respective variables
    MANUFACTURER_ID = Integer.valueOf(tempManufacturerID);
    ITEM_NUMBER = Integer.valueOf(tempItemNumber); 

}
```

.

.

### SOLUTION

```
public InventoryItem(
        long UPC, 
        Category category, 
        Unit_Of_Measure unitOfMeasure, 
        String binLocation, 
        String aisle, 
        String name, 
        String description, 
        short itemsPerUOM,
        int unitsInStock,
        int unitsLastReceived){

    this.UPC = UPC;
    this.category = category;
    this.unitOfMeasure = unitOfMeasure;
    this.binLocation = binLocation;
    this.aisle = aisle;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.itemsPerUOM = itemsPerUOM;
    this.unitsInStock = unitsInStock;
    this.unitsLastReceived = unitsLastReceived;
    this.MANUFACTURER_ID = (int)(this.UPC / 1000000); // <--So much nicer!
    this.ITEM_NUMBER = (int)((this.UPC % 1000000) / 10); // <--So much nicer!

}
```

Comment: Inspired by your comment I have a suggestion: send your UPC as string and then pare it to a Long value: e.g. Long.parseLong("000001000010"). Since you can have as many leading zeroes as 5 in your UPC code, this little patch should help you deal with corner cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a simple arithmetic mod / div action?

```
long manufacturerID = (long) UPC / 1000000L;
long itemNumber = (long) (UPC % 100000L) / 10;
```

Simple arithmetic without costly string operations is much better performance wise. It also looks far more elegant.

Comment: You beat me to answering my own question hehe. Just after I posted I thought of using modulus. So much more condense and readable, I don't even need it in the constructor!

Comment: Modulo should be by 1000000L to get first 6 digits. Fix that and will be a good answer. Division too.

Comment: I'm getting expected results with `UPC / 1000000` for the first 6 digits (Manufacturer ID) and `(UPC % 1000000) / 10` for the 7-11(Item Number)

Comment: @AndrzejBobak Upon further inspection I see that there is a huge bug since a UPC can start with 0. If the first digit is a zero everything is hopelessly broken. Would you suggest adding a leftmost 1 as a placeholder and modifying the calculations or would there be possible bugs with that as well?

Comment: The smallest possible 12 digit UPC would be 000001000010. I so far have a workaround where I add the leftmost 1 and then just mod or divide more to phase out that 1 in the manufacturer ID but since UPC is final this forces my UPC to have 13 digits instead of the standardized 12 and the data is no longer an accurate representation of the product's UPC

Comment: @Justin how is this number bypassed to your constructor? If it is sent as 000001000010 then you have a common mistake with numbers. Try Long.parseLong("000001000010"). See my comment to your question

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on integers/longs:

```
long longcode = 123456789012L;
long firstpart = longcode / 1000000L;
long secondpart = (longcode - 1000000L * firstpart) / 10L;
```

On strings, you can use [`substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) to get the string parts:

```
String str = Long.toString(UPC);
String tempManufacturerID = str.substring(0,6);
String tempItemNumber = str.substring(6,11);
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without converting to Strings? UPC, MANUFACTURER_ID and ITEM_NUMBER are all integers so I'm wondering if it's bad style to convert to a String just to substring and convert right back to an integer type.

Comment: It should be `String tempManufacturerID = str.substring(0,7);`. The substring method is now returning index 0 up to 5. And tempItemNumber is index 6-10 so it should be `str.substring(6,11)`

Comment: @MaxMeijer I think (0,6) is ok because its digits 1-6 inclusive which represent the MANUFACTURER_ID and 7-11 inclusive for ITEM_NUMBER so when referenced from a 0-index system I would want indices 0,1,2,3,4,5 and 6,7,8,9,10 respectively

Comment: @Justin I updated my answer to show how to do it using numbers. Updated it now to get only 5 digits for the second number.

Comment: @MaxMeijer Sorry, didn't notice it was only 5 digits in the second number.

Comment: @Szymon your code is overcomplicated. Additional variable, floor operation, additional division. It would need a lot of comments just to understand it.

Comment: @AndrzejBobak Simplified it as floor wasn't needed. Your code is nicer :)

Answer (score 0):

`Java` has a `String` built in method called `substring`.

```
String c = "abc".substring(2,3); // Output: b
```

Comment: `substring` is excluding the end index. String indexes start at 0. The correct way would be `"abc".substring(1,3)`. This will take index 1 and 2, so the second and third letters

Answer (score 0):

use `substring` method of `String` class. like

```
 `String tempManufacturerID = str.substring(0,7);`  //First 7 digits from index pos - 0 to pos - 6
```

Comment: This is 7 characters.